# Is it possible to be in 2 different networks in Corda?

Tags: corda

Can one node be in 2 different networks simultaneously, or i need to start another node for this? And if it's impossible how to merge networks, because i found only a few words about this in technical whitepaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda 3.1, a node can only be part of one network. There is no functionality to allow a node to connect to two databases, have two sets of configs, etc.

Comment: And what about merging networks? I can't find enough information in developers docs, but technical whitepaper refers to possibility to do this.